# Is there any tool available for getting internal structure(XML based) of the PDF file?

Tags: c#, pdf, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, acrobat

We are already working in MS-WORD 2007 with C#4.0(WIN FORM Application) by using open XML representation of the MS-WORD 2007 for splitting,Aggregate the word document.Now, We extending our work to supporting PDF Files.So, i would like to know if there is any tool available for getting internal structure(XML BASED) of the PDF file likewise Open XML representation for MS-OFFICE 2007?

Please enlighten me on this...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the PDF contain any marked content? Otherwise there is no XML structure you can extract

Comment: :yes may be.because,PDF was uploaded by user.So, We never expecting PDF contains marked content.Is there any other structure other than XML format?...